# Local git clone with source in WINDOWS

Tags: git, bitbucket, public-key, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to do a local git clone (On my pc) from bitbucket with sourcetree terminal.

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxx/example.git
```

And it drop the following error:

```
Permission denied (public key)
```

I have the public key but dont know how give it to sourcetree in windows.

Need help with that.

Regards.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket or https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go `Tools > Options` in SourceTree, it looks like you can add your SSH private key there:

[image]

There's also a dropdown that you can use to switch from OpenSSH to PuTTY, if that's what you're using as your SSH engine.